# Plotting minimum value across several columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have several columns in a pandas data frame and I want to plot the minimum value across several columns for each row. i.e.

```
np.random.seed(2020)
x = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ["x" , "y", "z"])
```

I just want to plot something like this:

```
plt.hist( min(df['x'], df['y'], df['z']) )
```

Comment: Is this what you need ..`df.min(axis=1).hist()` ?

Comment: `df.min(1).plot.hist();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`DataFrame.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) across axis 1 and the [`Series.hist`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.hist.html) method:

```
# Set up
np.random.seed(2020)
x = np.random.rand(10,3)
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns = ["x" , "y", "z"])

df.min(axis=1).hist()
```

[out]

[image]